# Data structure for handling a list of 3 integers

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm currently coding a physical simulation on a lattice, I'm interested in describing loops in this lattice, they are closed curved composed by the edges of the lattice cells. I'm storing the information on this lattice cells (by information I mean a Boolean variable saying if the edge is valuable or no for composing a loop) in a 3 dimensional Boolean array.

I'm now thinking about a good structure to handle this loops. they are basically a list of edges, so I would need something like an array of 3d integer vectors, each edge being defined by 3 coordinates in my current parameterization. I'm already thinking about building a class around this "list" object as I'll need methods computing the loop diameter and probably more in the future.

But, I'm definitely not so aware of the choice of structure I have to do that, my physics background hasn't taught me enough in C++. And for so, I'd like to hear your suggestion for shaping this piece of code. I would really enjoy discovering some new ways of coding this kid of things.

Comment: Why is an edge described by 3 coordinates ?

Comment: If it's always 3, why not use a fixed size array or a struct?

Comment: @Kindread True, it's two dimensional, but the I started to describe my system by giving 2 coordinates to the the center of each cell, the edge came after, and now my program points to an edge by using the first two coordinates of the cell and a third coordinates pointing to a specific edge of it. (in a non redundant way...)

Comment: If you need your program to do things with your cells besides knowing the edges, I would consider possibly storing the cells themselves as classes, and finding the edges for a cell via a method call on a cell. Each edge itself can be represented as a struct. I'm not familiar with lattices, but if they always have a fixed number of edges, you could then return each cell's edges as another struct with X edge structs in it, or if they are not fixed you could return them contained in a std::vector. You should store the edges struct/vector as a member variable on the cell object.

Comment: @Liam good if you mention any performance constraints.. 1000000 cells? speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two separate things. One is keeping track of all edges and allowing fast lookup of edge objects by an (int,int,int) index (you probably don't want `int` there but something like `size_t` or so). This is entirely independent from your second goal crating ordered subsets of these.

### General Collection (1)

Since your edge database is going to be sparse (i.e. only a few of the possible indices will actually identify as a particular edge), my prior suggestion of using a 3d matrix is unsuitable. Instead, you probably want to lookup edges with a hash map.

How easy this is, depends on the expected size of the individual integers. That is, can you manage to have no more than 21 bit per integer (for instance if your integers are `short int` values, which have only 16 bit), then you can concatenate them to one 64 bit value, which already has an [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) implementation. Otherwise, you will have to implement your own hash specialisation for, e.g., `std::hash<std::array<uint32_t,3>>` (which is also quite easy, and highly [stackable](https://stackoverflow.com/search)).

Once you can hash your key, you can throw it into an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and be done with it. That thing is *fast*.

### Loop detection (2)

Then you want to have short-lived data structures for identifying loops, so you want a data structure that extends on one end but never on the other. That means you're probably fine with an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or possibly with an [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) if you have very large instances (but try the vector first!).

I'd suggest simply keeping the index to an edge in the local vector. You can always lookup the edge object in your unordered_map. Then the question is how to represent the index. If Int represents your integer type (e.g. `int`, `size_t`, `short`, ...) it's probably the most consistent to use an [`std::array<Int,3>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) --- if the types of the integers differ, you'll want an [`std::tuple<...>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: Indeed, I need to be able to iterate and add edges as I'm constructing the loop until hitting back on the first edge (I'm only interested in closed loops). The most convenient for me is to end up with an array of loops (instances of a class). Each loop needs one of these iterative structures for constructing its geometry. Also, Until I have composed all the possible loops I don't know how much there are, so I need my array of loops to be expendable/"iteratible".

Comment: I'm not sure I really parse all that correctly. But it appears I suggested the wrong thing to you. So, you want a collection of edge objects, which you identify by a tuple of three integers and you need the collection to be ordered. Is that assumption correct? Then I could update the answer with a better suggestion.

Comment: @Liam: I've edited my answer. See if this helps you. Ping me, if you don't quite get something.